# android: How to preview non-default fragment xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Ok, this might be a little tricky, but I wonder if this is possible.

Let's say, I have a main activity layout -- which contains an `include` that includes one specific fragment -- named `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- some other things... -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/itemBelow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemAbove">
        <!-- load fragments here -->
    </include>
    <!-- some other things... -->
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and I have a fragment layout, for example: `fragment_1.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- something... -->
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know in `activity_main.xml`, I can preview `fragment_1.xml` by adding `tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1"` in `include`;

and in `fragment_1.xml`, I can preview the `activity_main.xml` by adding `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"` in the base `ConstraintLayout`.

But here comes the question: for re-usable layout design, there might be *another* fragment that shows in `include`, and if I follow method above -- let's say, in `fragment_2.xml` I write:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <!-- something... -->
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I would just see `fragment_1.xml` inside `activity_main.xml` in preview.

**Is there any possible way that shows `fragment_2.xml` inside `activity_main.xml` -- when previewing `fragment_2.xml` in Android Studio?**

Furthermore: if there's more `include`s inside `activity_main.xml`, would the method still works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is impossible (for now, anyway).

The layout preview does not execute any Android code (no Java, no Kotlin). All it does is parse the XML tree and show you what the XML says to show.

From [the `tools` documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolslayout):

> the layout preview cannot execute the activity code that normally applies the layout

When you use `tools:layout` for a `<fragment>` tag, you're saying "show this layout instead of a gray square". When you use `tools:showIn` on a root layout tag, you're saying "show this *other* layout instead of the normal preview". There's no "intelligence" here that can determine that you're asking the preview to show your view "inside" of another layout that doesn't include it. It just blindly shows you `activity_main`'s layout preview (which will, in turn, blindly include `fragment_1`'s layout).

---

To see this in extremely obvious terms, imagine these two layouts:

- `activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="second"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

- `itemview.xml`

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Despite the fact that there are no `<fragment>` or `<include>` tags in `activity_main.xml`, the layout editor preview for `itemview.xml` will only show you "first" and "second". The `tools:showIn` attribute simply completely overrides the normal preview.

Comment: It is sad to hear "impossible" while coding... but I guess it's a deal when it comes to IDE preview. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)